# Can I say my Dhamma is Kamma?

Tags: karma, pratityasamutpada, dhammas

I bear the brunt of my Karma. Nobody else. Self is so clearly elucidated by the theory of Kamma. Whatever I did in the past is responsible for what happens to me in the present and future. Effect of Kamma on self can not be neglected and I think I am nothing but a consequence of my Kamma in the past.

My question is: can I say my Dhamma is Kamma? If yes , can I also say Sabbe Kamma Anatta?

Answer (score 1):

I pay homage to the Buddha, my Karma and the Sangha.

I pay homage to the Buddha, the Karma and the Sangha.

I don't know...

I never heard anyone refer to the Dhamma as a possession or something that is spoken of  dualistically  like karma (my good dhamma, my bad dhamma). So just grammatically it doesn't really fit.

Really, these are just words. Ultimately we don't possess anything and there is more to the Dharma than just karma.

On the other hand, concepts in Buddhism fit together with such incredible grace that it can sort of seem like one concept is the same as the next concept but from another perspective or in another context.

I hope I'm not misunderstanding your question and I hope this helps.-metta

Comment: Thanks for the answer, You have not misunderstood. If Kamma is not Anatta then Kamma can not be Dhamma becasue Sabbe Dhamma Anatta.

Comment: Doesn't Mara follow bad Dhamma?

Comment: @DheerajVerma I think the word "Dhamma" has at least three meanings: 1) "any thing" 2) "anything that's taught or conceived of" 3) "everything the Buddha taught." Buddhists usually use it (and understand it) in the 3rd sense as meaning [Buddhavacana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhavacana) ... so I find it confusing when you talk about "my dhamma" and "bad dhamma".

Comment: I think it can be helpful to ponder how one concept relates to another concept. Mara? I would put it like this:    Mara tries to stop the Dhamma and tries to redirect us from the direction of liberation. Mara doesn't follow Dharma. Dhamma can't be bad. The closest thing to bad dharma would be "incorrect Dharma".

Comment: Ok. Mara follows incorrect Dhamma but so we can say correct and incorrect karma. I say Mara follows a Dhamma because as you said Dhamma is anything that is taught or conceived of... Mara follows what it conceives of.

Comment: See, your thinking is dualistic. If there is good Dhamma then there has to be bad dharmma...this is a tool of Mara.

Comment: What is the sound of one hand clapping?

Comment: There is no incorrect Dhamma either, if I said that I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In [AN 5.57](https://suttacentral.net/en/an5.57), we can find a wholesome way or skillful way to think about your relationship to your karma:

> “And for the sake of what benefit should a woman or a man, a
>   householder or one gone forth, often reflect thus: ‘*I am the owner of
>   my kamma, the heir of my kamma; I have kamma as my origin, kamma as my
>   relative, kamma as my resort; I will be the heir of whatever kamma,
>   good or bad, that I do*’? People engage in misconduct by body, speech,
>   and mind. But when one often reflects upon this theme, such misconduct
>   is either completely abandoned or diminished.
>
> “This noble disciple reflects thus: ‘*I am not the only one who is the
>   owner of one’s kamma, the heir of one’s kamma; who has kamma as one’s
>   origin, kamma as one’s relative, kamma as one’s resort; who will be
>   the heir of whatever kamma, good or bad, that one does. All beings
>   that come and go, that pass away and undergo rebirth, are owners of
>   their kamma, heirs of their kamma; all have kamma as their origin,
>   kamma as their relative, kamma as their resort; all will be heirs of
>   whatever kamma, good or bad, that they do.*’ As he often reflects on
>   this theme, the path is generated. He pursues this path, develops it,
>   and cultivates it. As he does so, the fetters are entirely abandoned
>   and the underlying tendencies are uprooted.

Comment: Sabbe Kamma Anatta if true means this kamma of Dhamma discussion is impermanent, changeable and cause of suffering. Therefore this discussion can not regarded as me, or mine or myself. One thus develops revulsion towards such kamma and becomes dispassionate about such discussion. In other words Sabbe Kamma Anatta means one should ignore or become dispassionate about this discussion and all discussions. Which means no learning can take place.

Comment: @DheerajVerma I don't see how your comment is related to ruben2020's answer.

Comment: @ChrisW ruben20220 edited his answer. He had said Sabbe Whatever Anatta which is wrong I guess.